# ExtJs6: Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#autogenerated_id') returns an empty array if the component has an itemId

Tags: extjs6

I have some ExtJs component.
I set **itemId** for it, but **id** is autogenerated.

Now `Ext.getCmp('autogenerated-id')` returns my component.
But `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#autogenerated-id')` returns an empty array.

But:
**Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[id=assets-information-form-1918]')** again returns my component. :)

I use ExtJs 6.5.3 classic.

It seems like itemId config property hides autogenerated id from Ext.ComponentQuery, so they become mutually exclusive.

**I don't need** other means for search or advice to set id for the component, to write letter to Sencha support or to write post on their forum.

**I need:**

- Means to force my `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#autogenerated-id')` to
  find the Component for which getId() returns 'autogenerated-id'.
- If it is not possible by design, I need a link to some documentation
  describing this behavior, a link to some bug report, or a filename and line number in ExtJs sources + a little snippet copy/paste from there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/modern/Ext.ComponentQuery.html)

> **Summary Provides** searching of Components within Ext.ComponentManager
>   (globally) or a specific Ext.container.Container on the document with
>   a similar syntax to a CSS selector. Returns Array of matching
>   Components, or empty Array.

Ext.ComonpentQuery.query('#itemId') returns and array. Your cold above is using the auto-generated id of the component. The # indicates to query based on the component itemId and not the component id.

Try

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('assets-information-form-1918');
```

which will return an array, as noted in the documentation.

```
Ext.getCmp()
```

> This is shorthand reference to Ext.ComponentManager#get. Looks up an
>   existing Ext.Component by id

Therefore it returns the component object.

Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#itemId')[0] would return the first object in the array.

Ext.ComponentQuery is the Sencha preferred method because it is more powerful when used as it does return an array so you an also query items by xtype and other attributes.

Comment: From your doc:
`You can search Components by their id or itemId property, prefixed with a #:`
Also this doc is clearly states that Ext.ComponentQuery.query('assets-information-form-1918') will search by xtype and nor by id neither by itemId.

So both your assumptions are incorrect. Also post contains too much text which is irrelevant to the question.